# Rails Devise Mailer - Add params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to use some personnal params in my mail (especially in Devise mailer) :

Here is my DeviseMailer

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

  mail = super
  @agency = Agency.find record.agency_id unless record.agency_id.blank?
  @color = color(@agency)
  @logo = logo(@agency)
  mail.subject = "[#{(@agency.blank?) ? 'Evasion & Découverte' : @agency.name}] Plus qu'une étape pour finaliser votre inscription !"
  mail.from = "#{(@agency.blank?) ? 'agence@evasion-et-decouverte.fr' : @agency.email}"

  mail
end
```

But I have an error when the email is send because "@color" or "@logo", or "@agency" are nil

Comment: may I know how you find color and logo?

Comment: In helpers, but @agency is nil i mailer view too !

Comment: what is the value for record.agency_id and your query (Agency.find record.agency_id) returning record? Have you debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok try this

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

  @agency = record.agency # or in your case record can be agency itself I dont know
  @color = @agency && @agency.color || SOME_DEFAULT_COLOR_VALUE
  @logo = @agency && @agency.logo || SOME_DEFAULT_LOGO

  email  = @agency && @agency.email || 'agence@evasion-et-decouverte.fr'
  opts[:subject] = "[#{@agency.name}] Plus qu'une étape pour finaliser votre inscription !"
  opts[:from] = email

  super
end
```

make sure the record `@agency = record.agency` is trying access is available in database

Comment: Thanks, this helps :)